# Is there a repeater control in C# windows form in Visual 2010?  Or an alternative?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, repeater

Is there a repeater control in C# windows form in Visual 2010 ? Or an alternative ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes there is.
From the Visual Studio Toolbox go to section Visual Basic PowerPacks and there you will find a DataRepeater control. Even if it says VB PowerPack it works with C# as well.

[image]

It will add a reference to following two assemblies:

- Microsoft.VisualBasic
- Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs

Answer (score 2):

Original answer : [Repeater in .NET Framework 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).
**Wrong**, thanks for the comments, only works in WebForms, not in WinForms.

What you could use is [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx), create your template, and use it as a Repeater.

Comment: Question asks for WinForms rather than Web Forms.